# PHP Mysqli Prepared Statement In a Function To Handle When Records Don't Exist

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have found lot of places on SO where pieces of what I want to do have been mentioned but I am having a hard time to get it to work when I combine. Here's what I want to do
I have a function that queries my database and shows the results. I want to check if no records exist to display the message "No records found".

```
public function testFun(){

        $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare('SELECT FirstName FROM users u JOIN usersandroles ur ON ur.UserId = u.id');
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rowCount = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();                
        if($rowCount === 0){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

My PHP page

```
$db = generaldb::getInstance();
$user = new User($db);
$result = $user->testFun();
if($result === FALSE){
    echo 'No rows';
}  else {
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $rows['FirstName'],'</br>';
    }
}
```

I keep getting "No rows"
 even though there are 5 records. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with :
`$rowCount = count($result);`

Comment: Your suggestion worked and now I can see all my records, but if there are no records it doesn't work. Instead of getting a "No rows" message I get a blank.